# Is there a way to load object data in void Load() without assigning each property separately (C#)?

Tags: c#, file, object, load

I'm working on a small WPF app to help me with file organisation. The class I store most of my data in is Project and it contains most of the data the app uses. Therefore, it has a lot of properties which I need to be saved and loaded from a file (around 20, using few as an example)

```
public DateTime Start { get; set; }
public DateTime End { get; set; }
public Int32 Count { get; set; }
public String Name { get; set; }
public HashSet<String> Files { get; set; }
```

As far as I know, loading an object can be done in 2 main ways:

I.

Project.cs

```
public Project Load( String file ) {
    Project project = json( file );    //to shorten the question
    return project;
}
```

MainWindow

```
Project project = new Project();
project = project.Load( file );
```

II.

Project.cs

```
public void Load( String file ) {
    Project project = json( file );    

    Start = project.Start;
    End = project.End;
    Count = project.Count;
    Name = project.Name;
    Files = project.Files;
}
```

MainWindow

```
Project project = new Project();
project.Load( file );
```

Can I somehow still use `void Load()` function, but assign the whole object at once?

I tried using `this = project;`, but it is read-only.

Comment: There is a method if you are using json.net, but if there are no performance requirements you can do it with two lines of code using reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json .net has a [method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm),

Quick and dirty way to do it using reflection

```
 var project = Json(file);    //to shorten the question

            foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(project));
            }

            return project;
```

More performant way using compilation this one is more advanced.
 But this looks like somewhat wrong in general when using wpf you should be using some MVVM pattern and the project should be the binding context of your view and you can set the created object from json with out making a copy of the object.

Comment: Thank you! First time using `Newton.Json`. Looked everywhere for that method but couldn't find it. You're saving me from a lot of bloated code!